# Can't access internet in kali virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I have Kali linux installed on Virtualbox 4.3 and my host OS is fedora 19 i have bridged the VM with fedora  but in kali it said that device not managed.
is there anyway to fix it?
thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution was this

```
vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Change `false` to `true`

And then

```
service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Downvoted. Connecting via an automatic service like *Network manager* defeats the whole purpose of using Kali, by announcing your presence to the whole world. The commands I posted establish a connection whenever you wish to, but they require a deliberate action on your part. This means you will not **inadvertently** announce your presence when you need to use Kali's resources.

Comment: this command is useful for any other distros, but I echo @MariusMatutiae in preferring the manual step for the specific case of Kali

Answer (score 21):

It is not broken, it is a feature. Kali comes with networking disabled by default to prevent denouncing your own presence through an unconscionable DHCP request.

You will have to start your connection with the traditional Linux means, something like

```
 sudo ifconfig eth0 up
 sudo dhclient eth0
```

or some such thing, depending on how you see fit.

Comment: Omg thank you so much. my eth0 would not connect to the bloody host internet wifi, I uninstalled and reinstalled VMplayer and kali like 4 times and it still wouldnt do it. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the VirtualBox network settings, I had to check "Cable Connected" (like suggested by another answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178399/no-longer-able-to-reach-the-internet-on-kali-linux/229266#229266).

Comment: This worked for me. All the other did not.

Answer (score 0):

connect your wireless to your pc, add the usb at usb filters in virtualbox,

it will be installed automatically start up your kali and you should see some wireless in your area.

Answer (score 0):

I clicked on the task bar->Wired-Connected->Connect to accomplish this through the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I must write this here!
My problem was F-Secure in host os. When I disabled it, everything started working.
(Note: Before I figured this out, I did make a ton of changes in network-manager and in vb-quest-additions, based on forums suggestions)

Answer (score 0):

set to Bridged Adapter in network, for the vm and open terminal and the terminal to type
--> service network-manager restart

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser Stack Exchange. Thanks for your contribution! Before posting an answer, please make sure your suggestion was not already posted by someone else, or that the scenario is not already covered in the question. In this case, OP said "`i have bridged the VM`" which indicates that they are already using the "bridge" option. Also, reading the top answer as well as the accepted answer, it makes it clear that the problem was somewhere else. I believe with these small guidelines, your future contributions to this community will be very appreciated. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try the following commands: `service network-manager restart`
2. If it is Kali Linux (Debian), you need to use the following command: `service networking restart`
3. If it is Centos 8, you need to use the following command: `nmcli c reload`

Answer (score -4):

A combination of the first two pieces of advice is what worked for me.
I was originally set to a bridged connection.  I wasn't able to access the internet.  I followed the first person's advice and typed

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
sudo dhclient eth0
```

and it didn't work.  Then I switched from bridged to NAT, still a no go.
Finally I `vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and changed **false** to **true** and restarted the service.
Voila, the service started.

Comment: Flagging a post as abusive also downvotes the post. Your recent edit doesn't help  in this case...

Comment: Just cool down a little bit and before you step away from the keyboard please accept the pending edit on your post so we can get your post into shape