# Dual boot Windows 10 and Kali, wireless drivers issue

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, drivers, kali-linux

So, sadly, every thread I come upon doesn't relate to my problem. Whenever I boot Kali 2016.1 live everything works fine except it doesn't connect to the internet. From what I gather, the following info should help:

```
root@kali:~#ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether *Some address* txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
    Stuff, stuff, and stuff
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1 net mask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scooped 0x10<host>
    loop txqueuelen 0 (Local Loopback)

root@kali:~# lspci -nnk
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3814]
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0041] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Lenovo QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:3545]
```

It would also be useful for me to note that I don't have a wired or wireless connection on the Kali boot, only when my USB is out and I boot in Windows (wireless).

UPDATE:
So I have found out that I need wireless firmware, specifically debian firmware, for my Wifi chip set. I have tried to boot Kali live from a USB with the firmware in /lib/firmware of the USB itself, but whenever I boot in, there is still no wlan interface. I think my problem now is I don't know how to boot in with the firmware in place.

1) I don't know the exact location that it should be.

2) I don't know how to boot live with the data there if it resets every time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't access internet in kali virtualbox](http://superuser.com/questions/678893/cant-access-internet-in-kali-virtualbox)

Comment: This is dual booting. I have to install firmware from what I gather, I even have the firmware and am sitting on my Windows desktop trying to figure out how to put the firmware in my Kali USB. (effectively)

Answer (score 0):

That is not a bug. Kali will not establish an internet connection unless you do it yourself with:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
sudo dhclient eth0
```

Comment: I just tried that xD
Sadly, I do need firmware that was not given with the system. I'm installing that now. Thanks for the help though :)